# Can not register using StackExchange registration

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts, stack-exchange-openid, sign-up

I was always using my Google Open ID account to get to stack overflow, but since I have to use 3rd party internet access and would prefer not to store google cookies on those machines.

I thought it would be a good idea to create stackoverflow registration and use that in less secure environments, in case cookie got stolen I would not get Google account compromised (no offence to stack).

I can complete registration, then get confirmation email, then confirm it. When I confirm registration I get to Registration successful page, but when I try to log in using stack option, I get this.

[image]

I can go through registration process multiple times, get multiple confirmation emails.
One thing I am doing that might be 'out of ordinary' I am registering on chrome on laptop, but confirming on my phone.

Comment: Have you tried creating an account directly on http://openid.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Could you paste it as answer, it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try signing up on http://openid.stackexchange.com directly

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @LIUFA can you describe exactly what you did please? Did it work by signing up on your laptop and confirming on your mobile?

Comment: Yes I registered using laptop, then confirmed email on my mobile. After that I was able to log in using stack exchange using laptop, what previously was producing screenshot above.